# Getting the setter function of a Python property

Tags: python, properties, getter-setter

I'm using a GUI module with an `onchange` parameter.

Currently I have a `Settings` object that contains properties, and I want to bind them to my GUI.

But my GUI only accepts *setter functions*, and not *variables*, so I need to get the setter function of my property.

Here is the `Settings` code:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "Jhon Doe"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if value.count(" ") > 1:
            self._name = value
```

Here is the (simplified) GUI code:

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu
from settings import Settings

settings = Settings()

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

menu = pygame_menu.Menu('My menu', 600, 600)

menu.add.text_input('Name :', default='John Doe', onchange=settings.name)
menu.add.button('Quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)
menu.mainloop(surface)
```

Comment: is this the original code? Then I think there might be a spelling mistake in getter `attirbute`

Comment: Yes, sorry... Not the original code, but it's exactly what I do (without the typo). Like it says, it's an example code. Fixed now.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Post [mre], incl. how you use your class and full traceback you get. The purpose of the setter is to bind `value` to `self._.attribute`.

Comment: What do you want it for? Please update your question with an example of what you want, pretending you can get this attribute.

Comment: your question is not clear. i assume u want to be able to set the value to the attribute .. `property` class and the getters and setters are very special functions, and to set the attribute u just need to do `instance.attribute = value`..

Comment: u wont be able to do `instance.attribute.setter(value)` as `instance.attribute` will call the getter function and return the value, as u pointed..

Comment: It isn't clear precisely what you want, `setter` is *not* a function attribute. Do you want the actual setter function `Object.attribute.fset`?

Comment: Updated the whole code. Is it clear now?

Comment: You dont' want the setter function, just use `def _callback(value): settings.name = value` then `menu.add.text_input('Name :', default='John Doe', onchange=_callback)`

Comment: or, `menu.add.text_input('Name :', default='John Doe', onchange=lambda value: settatr(settings, "name", value)`

Comment: Thank you for the lambda approach! I've tried using `lambda value: self.name = value` first, but it didn't worked. But I can't do all the setters since I have many many lany settings...

Comment: Can you put an answer so I can mark it as accepted answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the actual function, that is written as a method so it requires the instance. Just do what you'd do in this situation, whether there were a `property` or not:

```
def _callback(value):
    settings.name = value

menu.add.text_input('Name :', default='John Doe', onchange=_callback)
```

Or, alternatively,

```
menu.add.text_input('Name :', default='John Doe', onchange=lambda value: setattr(settings, "name", value))
```